# How to reference the AppDelegate from a Today View Widget?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

So I have a Today View widget built off of my main application, and I'm trying to access some stored data (via CoreData). But when I am creating the lazy variable to handle one of my entities, it fails to compile. I understand the error that it throws, but I'm not sure how to handle/fix it.

```
lazy var managedObjectContext : NSManagedObjectContext? = {
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
    if let managedObjectContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext {
        return managedObjectContext
    }
    else {
        return nil
    }
    }()
```

The error gets thrown at on line 2 at ..."as AppDelegate" that it is an "Undeclared use of AppDelegate." Which I guess makes sense because AppDelegate is in the base application folder and not in the widget's folder. But I am at a loss of how to replace or repair this so that the code will compile and function. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. Extensions are entirely separated binaries from your main app bundle, which is where your app delegate resides in. You will have to either make a shared library that will be used by your main app bundle and extension, or do a lot of copy-pasting code (the former method is preferred).

From the [developer guides](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionScenarios.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH21-SW1):

> You can create an embedded framework to share code between your app
>   extension and its containing app. For example, if you develop an image
>   filter for use in your Photo Editing extension as well as in its
>   containing app, put the filter’s code in a framework and embed the
>   framework in both targets.

You don't have to create a formal linkable library if you don't want. Just make sure that the library you are writing doesn't reference APIs that are not available for extensions.

> Make sure your embedded framework does not contain APIs unavailable to
>   app extensions, as described in [Some APIs Are Unavailable to App
>   Extensions](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH2-SW6).
>   If you have a custom framework that does contain such APIs, you can
>   safely link to it from your containing app but cannot share that code
>   with the app’s contained extensions. The App Store rejects any app
>   extension that links to such frameworks or that otherwise uses
>   unavailable APIs.