# iMessage Extension with Parse

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, parse-platform, imessage

I am trying to build an iMessage extension for my app but require Parse to pull data. The issue I am running into is when I mark my appDelegate file to target the extension I get the error :

```
'sharedApplication is unavailable.' Use view controller based solutions where appropriate instead
```

I am guessing the issue is because Parse is never initializing. Has anyone encountered this or know how to work around it?

Here is my parse initialization on the appDelegate :

```
Parse.enableLocalDatastore()

    let parseConfiguration = ParseClientConfiguration(block: { (ParseMutableClientConfiguration) -> Void in
        ParseMutableClientConfiguration.applicationId = "e81dbc81e92cedd3fbd2e11a175c39d454ca2938df"
        ParseMutableClientConfiguration.clientKey = "431a68273c2a3a60d9cx43f5e9f1b32ad15350de2"
        ParseMutableClientConfiguration.server = "http://ec2-47-xx-xx-21.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:80/parse"
    })

    Parse.initialize(with: parseConfiguration)
```

Comment: can you post your parse initialization code and the code where you try to access your app delegate from your extension? The error is because there is no access to sharedApplication from your extension...your main app may/may not be running when people are using the extension, so there is no access to the appDelegate.

Comment: I added the parse initialization, I am not sure how to access the appDelegate from the extension

Comment: you can't. will post the answer in a minute.

Comment: added an answer for you with a link to a good explanation in another SO answer. I don't use Parse, but have done the same thing successfully with Firebase so let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

The appDelegate instance that is available across your main app is not reachable to your iMessage extension, same issue discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28184315/how-to-reference-the-appdelegate-from-a-today-view-widget).

To achieve the same behavior, place the same initialization code you shared into the viewDidLoad() method of your iMessage extension's initial `MSMessagesAppViewController`, or anywhere else you know will get called before you first try to access Parse.